# Can I use an ASP form to POST JSON Data to an API?

Tags: json, rest, api

I`m having a form in ASP with 3 simple fields . I`m trying to POST that form with JSON but I don`t know anything about JSON code. I`m trying to find some scripts but I don`t really know where to start looking and how to combine them with ASP!

Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Your controller post method should take a model as a parameter which matches the fields on the form, from there you can do whatever you want with it. You don't need to post in a JSON format if you have an asp form.

Comment: well.. I`m using this form in order to send a SMS. So the SMS provider now uses an API which reads JSON data. So I guess that there is no other way than POSTing JSON data to their API. :(

Comment: The usual way to do it would be to create a javascript AJAX call directly to their API bypassing the normal post method on the form so it doesnt hit your controllers at all.